# CSS Background Color Not Filling Inside The Text

Tags: html, css

I Am Currently Learning CSS And Tackled Around An Issue, While I Try Adding A Background To A Div, background does not fills entirely as shown in the image below:-
[image: div_image]

As You Can See Here, the white background color is not filling inside the text background.
my code is below:-

```html
function popup() {
        const popup = document.createElement('div');
        popup.classList.add('popup');
        popup.innerHTML = `
        <div class="popup_inner">
        <h1>Change Logs</h1>
        <h3>1.0.0 -> 1.0.1</h3>
        <p>1. Added Change Logs<br/>2. Added First User Interface</p>
        <button class="close_button" onclick="document.querySelector('.popup').remove()">X</button>
        </div>
        <style>
            .popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.popup_inner {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.close_button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close_button:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
        </style>`;
        document.body.appendChild(popup);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the green background? Apart from the broken `<br/>` tag your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/20yaqk3m/

Comment: hello @MattHamer5 as per you, i have updated the whole code, but this thing doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

you have have applied a white backgroud to the div. To change the colour try targetting the `.popup_inner` class as follows:

```css
.popup_inner {
background-color: beige;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
position: relative;
min-width: 300px;
min-height: 300px;
max-width: 500px;
max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup_inner">
<h1>Change Logs</h1>
<h3>1.0.0 -> 1.0.1</h3>
<p>1. Added Change Logs</br>2. Added First User Interface</p>
<button class="close_button" onclick="document.querySelector('.popup').remove()">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't seems to work